# How to scale fixed size HTML5 webapp games?

Tags: iphone, css, html, ipad, web-applications

I am developing a fixed size HTML5 DOM-based game.  It got animations and graphics naturally.  It is fixed at 1000px x 620px but I cant make the game scale down proportionally for different sizes of devices.  I fits nicely on iPad but I only see part of the game on iPhone for example.

I thought it was easy thing to do to just scale the whole thing down (inc. graphics) but I can't find a solution for that.

What are my options, right now I am thinking of 3 totally diffenct CSS with media queries one for iPad, iPad mini and iPhone.  but its seem to be a lot of extra work to do.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try iframing your page and using standard transforms to scale it to the size you need. It is probably better to make your game non height/width dependent, but this may work to fix the issue quickly:

```
iframe {
    -ms-zoom: 0.25;
    -transform: scale(0.25);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.25);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Thx for the solution Matthew, my initial test went well with iFrame and it seem to work well. But could you elaborate, perhaps on a more optimal solution for fixed size games, so I can prepare better for my next one ?